# Powershell variables in Add-MailboxPermission Distribution Group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My Powershell Code till now:

`Add-MailboxPermission -Identity 'user1' -User "user2"  -AccessRights 'FullAccess'`

it works for specified users
My Question is how can i add a variable instead of user1 or user2?

For Example every Member in a DistributionGroup should get full access on user1:

`$group1 =  Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity group1`

`$group2 = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity group2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not give the permissions to the group directly?

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity 'user1' -User "group1"  -AccessRights 'FullAccess'
```